# Efficient way to write gitlab ci script

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitalb CI pipiline as follows.

Stage A

- job1
- job2
- job3

Stage B

- job1

In all the jobs in both stages, first package dependencies are installed. How can I handle this in an efficient way so that the total pipeline running time is the least. Also I can use multiple runners so job1, job2, job3 can run in parallel. Also multiple pipelines can run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a [`cache:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) rule to cache your dependencies. Use an appropriate `key:` on the cache to ensure the cache is resorted at appropriate points.

See also: [caching dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html)

Comment: ty @sytech The problem is I have multiple runners that I can use to run jobs parallelly. So to cache it for multiple runners I will have to store cache in s3. But then what will happen when multiple pipelines run at once.Will it be overwritten or what is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can set the `key:` appropriately to keep the cache around for as long as you see it is valid. The first time the jobs run, things obviously may not be cached yet, but afterwards it should be cached. For example, you can set the `key` to `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` so all builds on the same branch will leverage the same cache. There are many ways to configure this. See linked doc for more info @Origin